# Generated docx is empty when downloaded

Tags: node.js, meteor, download, file-generation

This is a Meteor-app. I need to generate a docx-file and download it. 
I am testing it by running: localhost:3000/download.

Word file is generated, but it is totally empty.

Why? I would appreciate any advice!

This is my server-side code:

```
const officegen = require('officegen');
const fs = require('fs');

Meteor.startup(() => {

WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/download', function(req, res, next) {

    const filename = 'test.docx';

    let docx = officegen('docx')

    // Create a new paragraph:
    let pObj = docx.createP()

    pObj.addText('Simple')
    pObj.addText(' with color', { color: '000088' })
    pObj.addText(' and back color.', { color: '00ffff', back: '000088' })

    pObj = docx.createP()

    pObj.addText(' you can do ')
    pObj.addText('more cool ', { highlight: true }) // Highlight!
    pObj.addText('stuff!', { highlight: 'darkGreen' }) // Different highlight color.

    docx.putPageBreak()

    pObj = docx.createP()

    let out = fs.createWriteStream(filename);

    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Disposition': `attachment;filename=${filename}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
      });

    res.end(docx.generate(out));

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that docx.generate(out) is an async function: when calling `res.end(docx.generate(out))` you end the request right now while you start generating the docx in the file `test.docx`. Hence the doc does not exist **yet**.

You should modify your code to send over the file directly like this:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Disposition': `attachment;filename=${filename}`,
    'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
  });
docx.generate(res)
```

If you still need the file on the server side you can use another approach waiting for the file being generated ([see here](https://github.com/Ziv-Barber/officegen/issues/307#issuecomment-486795854))

Comment: Nice! You saved my day! Thank you, Victor! :)